# Rails use method from one js file to another js file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, scope, filepath, production

I am developing a rails app. It has javascript functionality in app/assets/javascript. Now I have multiple javascript files. I want to use method from one javascript file in another file. 
I tried export, import concept.

My doubt is what should be the path in import? cause I am running this app in local environment.

if my path is this

"/home/manoharsinhrana/workspace/copy/housing.ads.service/app/assets/javascripts/ad_products/utility.js it "

It would not work in production.